# cannot receive time exceeded message

Tags: go, icmp

I'm doing some tests based on the idea of [pwnat](http://samy.pl/pwnat/), it introduced a method for NAT traversal without 3rd party: the server sends ICMP echo request packets to the fixed address(for example, `3.3.3.3`) where no echo replies won't be returned from, the client, pretending to be a hop on the Internet, sends an ICMP Time Exceeded packet to the server, expect the NAT in the front of the server to forward the ICMP time exceeded message to the server.
After I pinged to `3.3.3.3`, then I run the code below in `192.168.1.100` to listen ICMP messages in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/icmp"
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
)

func main() {
    c, err := icmp.ListenPacket("ip4:icmp", "0.0.0.0")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("listen error", err)
    }
    rb := make([]byte, 1500)

    for {
        n, _, err := c.ReadFrom(rb)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("read err: %s\n", err)
        }
        reply, err := icmp.ParseMessage(1, rb[:n])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("parse icmp err:", err)
            return
        }

        switch reply.Type {
        case ipv4.ICMPTypeTimeExceeded:
            if _, ok := reply.Body.(*icmp.TimeExceeded); ok {
                // internet header(20 bytes) plus the first 64 bits of the original datagram's data
                //fmt.Println("recv id ", binary.BigEndian.Uint16(timeExceed.Data[22:24]))
                fmt.Printf("ttl exceeded\n")
            }
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

and a program which runs in `192.168.2.100` to send forged time exceeded message to `192.168.1.100`:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/icmp"
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func sendTtle(host string) error {
    conn, err := net.Dial("ip4:icmp", host)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // original IP header
    h := ipv4.Header{
        Version:  4,
        Len:      20,
        TotalLen: 20 + 8,
        TTL:      64,
        Protocol: 1,
    }
    h.Src = net.ParseIP(host)
    h.Dst = net.ParseIP("3.3.3.3")
    iph, err := h.Marshal()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ip header error", err)
        return err
    }

    // 8 bytes of original datagram's data
    echo := icmp.Message{
        Type: ipv4.ICMPTypeEcho, Code: 0,
        Body: &icmp.Echo{
            ID: 3456, Seq: 1,
        }}

    oriReq, err := echo.Marshal(nil)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("Marshal error")
    }
    data := append(iph, oriReq...)

    te := icmp.Message{
        Type: ipv4.ICMPTypeTimeExceeded,
        Code: 0,
        Body: &icmp.TimeExceeded{
            Data: data,
        }}

    if buf, err := te.Marshal(nil); err == nil {
        fmt.Println("sent")
        if _, err := conn.Write(buf); err != nil {
            return errors.New("write error")
        }
    } else {
        return errors.New("Marshal error")
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    argc := len(os.Args)
    if argc < 2 {
        fmt.Println("usage: prpgram + host")
        return
    }
    if err := sendTtle(os.Args[1]); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to send TTL exceeded message: ", err)
    }
}
```

the problem is `192.168.1.100` cannot receive the message. What're the possible reasons?

Comment: No, I set `Dst` to `3.3.3.3` on purpose to pretend the time exceed message is caused by the echo request sent by `192.168.2.100` to `3.3.3.3`.

Comment: Ok. Your code works for me. The server prints "ttl exceeded". Are you sure there is connectivity between your machine at 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.2.100 ? Those machines sounds like they might be on different subnets, so make sure you can route between them and there's no firewalls messing things up. Try to debug with tcpdump on both the client and the server, you'll see if the packet appears, and looks like it should.

Comment: thanks for the reply. There is connection between the two subnets. It seems the router discards the packet from wireshark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has no problem. If you run your code in the same network(I mean no NAT/router involvement), the program will receive time exceeded message as expected. The reason is the theory pwnat uses doesn't work nowadays.

- First, you didn't get the identifier of the echo request sent by
  `192.168.2.100` to `3.3.3.3`, the identifier will be uniquely
  mapped to an external query ID by NAPT(if any) so that it can route
  future ICMP Echo Replies with the same query ID to the sender. According to [rfc 3022 ICMP error packet modifications section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3022#section-4.3),

  > In a NAPT setup, if the IP message embedded within ICMP happens to be
  > a TCP, UDP or ICMP Query packet, you will also need to modify the
  > appropriate TU port number within the TCP/UDP header or the Query
  > Identifier field in the ICMP Query header.
- Second, according to rfc 5508:

  > If a NAT device receives an ICMP Error packet from the private realm,
  > and the NAT does not have an active mapping for the embedded payload,
  > the NAT SHOULD silently drop the ICMP Error packet.

So the forged time exceeded message wouldn't get through. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985793/is-pwnat-still-working/38223370#38223370) is more details about this.